# R / dplyr : How to use filter functions in conjunction with the pipelining %>% operator?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm sure there's an idiom for doing this, but how exactly do I pipeline a boolean mask or row selection to a filter operation using dplyr.

For example, here I want to select out rows of foo for which id is duplicated:

```
foo$id %>% duplicated %>% filter(foo ??)
```

I can do this with an anonymous function, but there must be a better way than:

```
foo$id %>% duplicated %>% function(x) foo[x,]
```

Comment: Could you use `foo %>% filter(duplicated(id))` instead?

Comment: Can you please provide foo to make this a minimal working code otherwise this is grounds for having a question closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to send vector down the pipe when `dplyr` is really meant to be used with table-like objects so you should be sending the whole data.frame (assuming that's what `foo` is. For example

```
library(dplyr)
foo <- data.frame(id=sample(1:5, 25, replace=T), val=runif(25))
foo %>% filter(!duplicated(id))
```

If you really only want the ID's, then add

```
foo %>% filter(!duplicated(id)) %>% select(id)
```